# Anyone have lyrics to "Ich schenk dir mein Herz" by Peter Reusch?

Tags: lyrics, rock, pop, language

As part of my German education, I'm taping old 1970s and 1980s hits to the bathroom wall -- along with translations -- and singing them in the shower. I'm sure my neighbors love me.

The compilation CD *Herzen brauchen Zärtlichkeit* has been a great source of material, but I'm having trouble finding the lyrics for "Ich schenk dir mein Herz," which is sung by Peter Reusch on the album.

(Among other notable moments on the album, this song has the dubious honor of using more "orchestra hit" keyboard notes in a row than anything else I've heard*.)

The jacket for the album does not contain any lyrics. If I understand correctly, he at one point repeats the line "so wie im Hollywood" or "so wie in Hollywood" a zillion times. (I don't know my prepositions very well yet.)

I'm moving on to another song for the moment, but I'm hoping that in the long term, someone can help me out.

Anybody got a link to *der Songtext* for this?

===

Edit: I might have been a little hard on the guy. Viewing a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDatHMzgHts) of this song again, I'm impressed by how well he's able to sell the song with minimal resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't quite get one word/phrase, but might be good enough for the shower ;)

enjoy

```
Halt dich fest, wir werden fliegen
Träume siegen irgendwann einmal
dein kleines Herz kannte nur Lügen
du, ich bin ab heute für dich da

so wie in Hollywood, Hollywood, Hollywood
davon träum ich jede Nacht
so wie in Hollywood, Hollywood, Hollywood
wo das Glück den Siegern lacht

ich schenk dir mein Herz
vergess jeden Schmerz
wir werden uns lieben
du gibst mir dafür ein Lächeln von dir
wir werden uns lieben
ich schenk dir mein Herz
nimm alles von mir
wir werden uns lieben
die Tränen sind weit
jetzt kommt unsre Zeit
wir werden uns lieben

Hand in Hand gehen wir und träumen
nichts mehr tut uns in der Seele weh
weiße Vögel in den Bäumen
singen nur für uns ???

so wie in Hollywood, Hollywood, Hollywood
davon träum ich jede Nacht
so wie in Hollywood, Hollywood, Hollywood
wo das Glück den Siegern lacht

ich schenk dir mein Herz
vergess jeden Schmerz
wir werden uns lieben
du gibst mir dafür ein Lächeln von dir
wir werden uns lieben
ich schenk dir mein Herz
nimm alles von mir
wir werden uns lieben
die Tränen sind weit
jetzt kommt unsre Zeit
wir werden uns lieben
```